# Are there tools (imagemagick, graphicmagik) that use zopfli compression as part of their stack?

Tags: imagemagick

The title pretty much sums it up, are there any good batch type tools that provide high level of compression such as zopfli when creating optimized images and underlying paginated formats (TIFF, PDF)?

Are there tools (imagemagick, graphicmagik) that use zopfli compression as part of their stack?

Thanks!
-D

Comment: Hi dhartford, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: ImageOptim and zopflipng apparently allows you to use zopfli on PNG:s so the answer is yes.